# No ragdolls and minimal player models

Tags: counter-strike-source

I've had CS:S for about 6 years now, and I never realized that there should be ragdoll physics for dead people, and that there should be more than one player model per team (though I thought it was odd). At the moment, people just disappear when they die, and there is only one model per team.

I thought I fixed it the other day using the console commands `cl_ragdoll_physics_enable 1`
 and `cl_minmodels 0`, but I found out I have to do them every time I restart the game. Is there a config file I can edit, or some options I'm missing to make this persistent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a file containing those commands and host_writeconfig all in seperate lines and save it as autoexec.cfg in C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\SteamApps\common\Counter-Strike Source\cstrike\cfg